# Finding time difference based on distinct ids in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I would like to find the day difference between the latest and the 2nd latest distinct `order_id` for each user.

The intended output would be:

```
user_id | order_diff
   1    |     1
   3    |     7
   8    |     1
```

`order_diff` represents the difference in days between 2 distinct `order_id`. In the event that there are no two distinct `order_id` (as in the case for user id 9), the result is not returned.

In this case, the `order_diff` for `user_id` `1` is 1 since the day difference between his 2 distinct `order_id` is 1. However, there is no `order_diff` for `user_id` 9 since he has no 2 distinct `order_id'.

This is the dataset:

```
user_id order_id    order_time
1       208965785   2016-12-15 17:14:13
1       201765785   2016-12-14 17:19:05
1       203932785   2016-12-13 20:41:30
1       209612785   2016-12-14 20:14:32
1       208112785   2016-12-14 20:27:08
1       205525785   2016-12-14 17:01:26
1       208812785   2016-12-14 20:18:23
1       206432785   2016-12-11 20:32:20
1       206698785   2016-12-14 10:50:15
2       209524795   2016-11-26 18:06:21
3       206529925   2016-10-01 10:43:57
3       203729925   2016-10-08 10:43:11
4       204876145   2016-09-24 10:23:49
5       203363157   2016-07-13 23:56:43
6       207784875   2017-01-04 12:21:21
7       206437177   2016-06-25 02:40:33
8       202819645   2016-09-09 11:47:27
8       202819645   2016-09-09 11:47:27
8       202819646   2016-09-08 11:47:27
9       205127187   2016-06-05 22:21:18
9       205127187   2016-06-05 22:21:18
11      207874877   2016-06-17 16:49:44
12      204927595   2016-11-28 23:05:40
```

This is the code that I am currently using:

```
SELECT e1.user_id,datediff(e1.order_time,e2.time), e1.order_id FROM
sales e1
JOIN
sales e2
ON
e1.user_id=e2.user_id
AND
e1.order_id = (SELECT distinct order_id FROM sales temp1 WHERE temp1.order_id =e1.order_id ORDER BY order_time DESC LIMIT 1)
AND
e2.order_id = (SELECT distinct order_id FROM sales temp2 WHERE temp2.order_id=e2.order_id ORDER BY order_time DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
```

My output does not produce the desired output and it also ignores the cases where `order_ids` are the same.

**Edit**: I would also like the query to be extended to larger datasets where the 2nd most recent `order_time` may not be the `min(order_time)`

Comment: Hi Ben, can you show what you have tried and what issues you are having with it?

Comment: Hello! I just added the code that I am using but the output is far from what I need

Comment: can you provide a SQL Fiddle or DB Fiddle to play with ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e3cc0

The dataset here is slightly different

Comment: Amend the question (or the fiddle) accordingly

Comment: just imported the dataset above to the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6e53/2):

```
select user_id, 
   datediff(max(order_time), 
            ( -- Scalar Subquery to get the 2nd largest order_time
              select max(order_time)
              from orders as o2
              where o2.user_id = o.user_id              -- same user
                and o2.order_time < max(o.order_time)   -- but not the max time
            )
           ) as diff
from orders as o
group by user_id
having diff is not null -- if there's no 2nd largest time diff will be NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Following would work:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    (`user_id` int, `order_id` int, `order_time` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO orders
    (`user_id`, `order_id`, `order_time`)
VALUES
(1,208965785,'2016-12-15 17:14:13'),
(1,201765785,'2016-12-14 17:19:05'),
(1,203932785,'2016-12-13 20:41:30'),
(1,209612785,'2016-12-14 20:14:32'),
(1,208112785,'2016-12-14 20:27:08'),
(1,205525785,'2016-12-14 17:01:26'),
(1,208812785,'2016-12-14 20:18:23'),
(1,206432785,'2016-12-11 20:32:20'),
(1,206698785,'2016-12-14 10:50:15'),
(2,209524795,'2016-11-26 18:06:21'),
(3,206529925,'2016-10-01 10:43:57'),
(3,203729925,'2016-10-08 10:43:11'),
(4,204876145,'2016-09-24 10:23:49'),
(5,203363157,'2016-07-13 23:56:43'),
(6,207784875,'2017-01-04 12:21:21'),
(7,206437177,'2016-06-25 02:40:33'),
(8,202819645,'2016-09-09 11:47:27'),
(8,202819645,'2016-09-09 11:47:27'),
(8,202819646,'2016-09-08 11:47:27'),
(9,205127187,'2016-06-05 22:21:18'),
(9,205127187,'2016-06-05 22:21:18'),
(11,207874877,'2016-06-17 16:49:44'),
(12,204927595,'2016-11-28 23:05:40');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT dt2.user_id, 
       MIN(datediff(dt2.latest_order_time, 
                dt2.second_latest_order_time)) AS order_diff 
FROM (
 SELECT o.user_id, 
        o.order_time AS latest_order_time,  
        (SELECT o2.order_time 
         FROM orders AS o2 
         WHERE o2.user_id = o.user_id AND 
               o2.order_id <> o.order_id 
         ORDER BY o2.order_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS  second_latest_order_time 
 FROM orders AS o 
 JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(order_time) AS latest_order_time 
       FROM orders 
       GROUP BY user_id) AS dt 
   ON dt.user_id = o.user_id AND 
      dt.latest_order_time = o.order_time 
) AS dt2 
WHERE dt2.second_latest_order_time IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY dt2.user_id;

| user_id | order_diff |
| ------- | ---------- |
| 1       | 1          |
| 3       | 7          |
| 8       | 1          |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mnLm49VZRcEJSmRBGjEpoV/0)

---

**Details:**

- We determine maximum `order_time` for a `user_id` in a sub-select query ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)). We can alias it as `latest_order_time`.
- We `Join` this result-set to the `orders` table. This will help us in considering only the row(s) with maximum value of `order_time` for a `user_id`.
- Now, we use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to determine the maximum `order_time` value for the same user, out of the rest of `order_id` value(s). We can alias it as `second_latest_order_time`.
- Finally, use this as a Derived Table again, and remove all the cases where `second_latest_order_time` is `null`, and calculate `datediff()` for the rest.
- A final `Group By` is needed, as your data has multiple entries for a

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT user_id, 
   DATEDIFF(MAX(order_time), MIN(order_time)) as order_diff
FROM orders
GROUP BY user_id
   HAVING order_diff > 0;
```

Here is a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e3cc0/13) to test it.

Comment: Thank you. However it doesnt work if the 2nd most recent order is not the minimum

Comment: Well, you just edited your question to mention that. My answer solves your original question perfectly, I guess.

Comment: You need to update the data in your question as well to include examples of what exactly you need. Otherwise, my answer produces the desired result indicated in the question.

Comment: My apologies for that. I didnt realize the flaw until I saw the answers. Will update it now